# transfer home screen folders from one phone to another

Tags: google-pixel, home-screen-folders

I transferred my Android phone backup from a Pixel 5 to a Pixel 6a today, but during the process accidentally selected a secondary Google account, which meant only apps associated with that account were added to the 6a.

Later, I added my primary Google account to the 6a, which also prompted Android to install apps associated with that account to the 6a.

The only problem is that my nice neat home screen app groupings are missing.

Most apps are not on the home screen(s) at all.

Do I have have to manually recreate these groupings, or is there a better way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, I think your only options are to recreate them manually or factory reset and go through the setup process again with the intended primary account.

Comment: Some app launcher allow to export/import their configuration including app grouping.